Short story about a box of grief I read in university
I would really appreciate help remembering a short story I read when I was majoring in creative writing some years back. Here are the details I remember:

it centers around a young boy in a woodworking class, and he is working on a project
his parents have just died in a car crash recently
the boy’s teacher delivers his finished woodwork project to the boy’s house, and it’s implied that the box becomes a symbol for his unprocessed grief, like a coffin
I believe the title is “A Box of Grief” but when I checked online, I couldn't find the story at all nor could I remember the author


Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. To make this work easier to identify, please add any information you have of the kind listed at the tag wiki for identification requests. This includes details about where and when you read it (how long ago is "some years back"?), what the publication date seemed to be, what the book looked like, what you remember of other stories in the book, etc. Please edit your question, don't provide the info in the comments. Thanks!
